# Delete all unapproved posts with one click using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm trying to add a button that deletes all unapproved posts based on  `t.boolean "is_approved"` status. I usually have hundreds posts due to some spamming issues. I have been trying as below but can't seem to be able to get the routes work for an action that doesn't apply to a specific post.

---

**manage_posts.html.erb**

```
<p><%= link_to 'delete all unapproved', destroy_unapproved_posts_url, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn-admin-action" %></p>
```

---

**posts_controller.rb**

```
  def destroy_unapproved
    Post.where(is_approved != true).destroy_all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to manage_posts_url, notice: 'Unapproved Posts are destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

---

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put 'destroy_unapproved', to: "posts#destroy_unapproved"
    end
  end
```

---

Comment: Why `put 'destroy_unapproved', to: "posts#destroy_unapproved"` when you are sending `delete` request? It should be `delete 'destroy_unapproved', to: "posts#destroy_unapproved"` in routes file

Answer (score 1):

Your route should be

```
  resources :posts do
    collection do
      delete 'destroy_unapproved'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define a [collection route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) here, instead of the [member route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes) that you have defined.

Member routes are meant to work on a particular member of the resource, whereas collection routes do not require the id of any member in the URL, and can work on the resource as a whole.

Also, as Deepesh has mentioned in the comment to original post, I would also recommend changing the route from `put` to `delete`